# How to use single quotes with new lines in prometheus alerts?

Tags: prometheus

I want to use single quote in a prometheus alert, but I can't newline in the description other than using double quotes. As I'm using `{{ $value | printf "%.2f" }}` in the description, I am unable to use double quotes so how can I make use of single quotes here? Any ideas?

```
- alert: MemoryHigh
        expr: (x_process_resident_memory_bytes / y_resident_memory_limit_bytes) * 100 > 90
        for: 2m
        labels:
          x: y
        annotations:
          summary: Memory high (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
          description: '{{ $labels.pod }} in {{ $labels.environment}} is using more than 90% of allocated RAM\n  Memory = {{ $value | printf "%.2f" }}\n  Environment = {{ $labels.environment}}'
```

I have also tried the description below putting new lines instead of using `\n` itself but it didn't work.

```
description: '{{ $labels.pod }} in {{ $labels.environment}} is using more than 90% of allocated RAM
             Memory = {{ $value | printf "%.2f" }}
             Environment = {{ $labels.environment}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation Prometheus alert templates is based on [Golang text/template and html/template packages](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/template/template.go).

Single quotes values behave like [raw string literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals).

You can escape the double quotes in the formatting function and set the description value in double quotes.

```golang
{{ $value | printf \"%.2f\" }}
```

You can also provide the description as [a scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#23-scalars).

```yaml
description: |
    {{ $labels.pod }} in {{ $labels.environment}} is using more than 90% of allocated RAM
    Memory = {{ $value | printf "%.2f" }}
    Environment = {{ $labels.environment}}
```